# Fastest way to insert many rows into sqlite db on iPhone

Tags: iphone, fmdb

Can someone explain what the best way to insert a lot of data on the iPhone using FMDB is?  I see things like using the beginTransaction command.  I'm honestly not sure what this or setShouldCacheStatements do.  I followed what code my coworker did so far, and this is what it looks like:

```
BOOL oldshouldcachestatements = _db.shouldCacheStatements;
[_db setShouldCacheStatements:YES];
[_db beginTransaction];
NSString *insertQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ values(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", tableName];
[tableName release];
BOOL success;

bPtr += 2;
int *iPtr = (int *)bPtr;
int numRecords = *iPtr++;

for (NSInteger record = 0; record < numRecords; record++) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Some business logic to read the binary stream  

    NSNumber *freq = aFreq > 0 ? [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100 * aFreq / 32768]: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-1.0];

    // these fields were calculated in the business logic section
    success = [_db executeUpdate:insertQuery,
               cID,                                                                                                   
               [NSNumber numberWithInt:position],                                                                       
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self stringForTypeA:typeA], [self stringForTypeB:typeB]],     // methods are switch statements that look up the decimal number and return a string
               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"r%i", rID],                                                               
               [self stringForOriginal:original],                                                                    
               [self stringForModified:modified],                                                                    
               freq];

    [pool drain];
}
[outerPool drain];

[_db commit];
[_db setShouldCacheStatements:oldshouldcachestatements];
```

Is this the fastest I can do?  Is the writing the limitation of sqlite?  I saw this: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19 and wasn't sure if this implementation was the best with fmdb, or if there was any other thing I can do.  Some other coworkers mentioned something about bulk inserts and optimziing that, but I'm not honestly sure what that means since this is my first sqlite encounter.  Any thoughts or directions I can go research?  Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

First of all, in most cases you do not have to be concerned about the performance of sqlite3, if you are not using it completely wrong.

The following things boost the performance of `INSERT` statements:

**Transactions**

As you already mentioned, transactions are the most important feature. Especially if you have a large amount of queries, transaction will **speed up your `INSERT`s by ~10 times**.

**PRAGMA Config**

Sqlite3 provides several mechanism which avoid the corruption of your database in the worst cases. In some scenarios, this is not needed. In others, it is absolutely essential. The following sqlite3 commands may speed up your `INSERT` statements. A normal crash of your app will not corrupt the database, but a crash of the OS could.

```
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF -- may cause corruption if the OS fails
PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY -- Insert statements will be written to the disk at the end of the transaction
PRAGMA cache_size = 4000 -- If your SELECTs are really big, you may need to increase the cache
PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY -- Attention: increases RAM use
```

**Deactivate Indicies**

Any SQL Index slows a `INSERT` statement down. Check if your table has some indices:

```
.indices <table_name>
```

If yes, DROP the `INDEX` and `CREATE` it after the transaction.

**One Select**

I do not see a way of using a BULK insert as you are generating new data. However, you could collect data and just perform one `INSERT` statement. This may boost up your performance dramatically, but it also rises the possibility of failure (syntax, for instance).
One hack meets another hack: As sqlite3 does not support this directly, you have to use the UNION command to collect all insert statements accordingly.

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename'
      SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION SELECT 'data3', 'data4'
UNION SELECT 'data5', 'data6'
UNION SELECT 'data7', 'data8'
```

**Statement Caching**

I would suggest to avoid the use of statement caching as there is a [unfixed issue](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/6) with this feature (and far as I know, it does not influence the performance dramatically).

**Memory Management**

The last point I'd like to mention is about ObjC. Compared to basic operations, memory management needs very very much time. Maybe you could avoid some `stringWithFormat:` or `numberWithDouble:` by preparing these variable outside the loop.

**Summary**

All in all, I don't think that you will have a problem with the speed of sqlite3 if you simply use **transactions**.

Comment: Very thorough answer, I don't see why the OP hasn't accepted it by now.

Comment: V.Good answer, the transaction enhance the transaction very well. Just I have one concern: Should I have to change the PRAGMA for SQLite or it's better to not mess with this Low level options?

Comment: @Saeed very probably it won't be necessary, but this really is depending on your use case (i.e. if high memory consumption is wanted or not). I have learnt to not really worry about the speed of sqlite, as long as you are using transactions and you are not completely 'misusing' sqlite.

If however, you are changing the parameters, make sure to read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) and test sufficiently.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I can't stress enough just how much of a difference transactions make. I'm inserting ~10,300 rows into an iOS sqlite database. It's around 7 seconds without transactions, just on 0.8 seconds within a transaction bracket.

Comment: @Andrew I absolutely agree with you. I've added a sentence to emphasise the importance.

Answer (score 9):

I found it really difficult to find a concrete code example on how to insert many rows really quickly. After much experimentation with FMDB and the help of the answer above, here's what I'm using at the moment:

```
[_objectController.dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db)
{
    [db open];
    [db setShouldCacheStatements:YES];

    NSArray *documentsJSONStream = responseObject[@"details"][@"stream"];

    static NSString *insertSQLStatment = @"INSERT INTO documents (`isShared`,`thumbnailURLString`,`userID`,`version`,`timestamp`,`tags`,`title`,`UDID`,`username`,`documentURLString`,`shareURLString`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    [db beginTransaction];
    for (NSDictionary *dJ in documentsJSONStream)
    {
        [db executeUpdate:insertSQLStatment withArgumentsInArray:@[dJ[@"isShared"],dJ[@"thumbnailURLString"],dJ[@"userID"],dJ[@"version"],dJ[@"timestamp"],dJ[@"tags"],dJ[@"title"],dJ[@"UDID"],dJ[@"username"],dJ[@"documentURLString"],dJ[@"shareURLString"]]];
    }
    [db commit];
    [db close];
 }];
```

Using inTransaction gave me strange FMDB is not open errors. If there are any suggestions on how to improve this, please let me know.